# LG Gram Wi-Fi disconnected while sleep mode

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, wifi-driver, lg-gram

I am using 14ZD980-GX50K (2018 edition). Wi-Fi is disconnected while it goes into sleep mode and I can never connect it again unless the device is re-booted.
I already re-installed the wifi driver but it does not help.

I know this cannot be solved easily. But at least I want to know how I can connect wifi again "without reboot".

The Wi-Fi icon on the lower-right corner completely disappears. In 'Network and Internet' Setting, 'Wi-Fi' sub-menu also disappears. So it seems there is no way I can connect to wifi again. When I re-boot, everything is okay

Comment: Check the WiFi device properties for some power saving setting and if possible disable it. This is often the solution for the same problem in Linux distros. I'm not using Windows now so I can't give you more precise instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer by myself.

In the device manager > Network adapters, disable Intel (R) Dual Band Wireless-AC82554, and then enable it.